# Solspace User form not submitting correctly

Tags: solspace-user, ee3

I have EE 3.3.2 and Solspace User 4.0.6 running.

I build the form templates and they appear to be rendered ok. The template tags pull the data correctly for the user:edit form and all the form elements are there.

But neither the user:edit nor the user:registration forms would submit. Upon hitting the submit button they all redirect to the domain without recording any data.

If I hack the rendered page in the browser to append ACT to the action (e.g. action="http://example.com/?ACT=33) I get a permission error.

Any clue, anyone?

Thanks!
Luke

```
<form id="member_form" method="post" action="http://example.com/"  >
<div class='hiddenFields'>
<input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="33" />
<input type="hidden" name="RET" value="http://example.com/member/registration-thank-you" />
<input type="hidden" name="params_id" value="26" />
<input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="ed7a4cdcdebe7b7349137c6ba5108d88b857f736" />
</div>

<p><label>Email Address <span class="required">*</span></label><input type="text" name="username" /></p>


<p><label>First Name <span class="required">*</span></label><input type="text" name="first_name" /></p>
<p><label>Last Name <span class="required">*</span></label><input type="text" name="last_name" /></p>

<p><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="accept_terms" value="y"  /> Accept <a href="http://example.com/about/disclaimer">Terms</a>? <span class="required">*</span></p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" /></p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the clue from Solspace support.

Apparently my htaccess www redirect was in discord with the path settings. I had to make sure if I redirect to www then the path must include www as well.